# Error while running Linux commands in Jupyter notebook on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been studying pandas for python. I am doing my practical work on Jupyter Notebook.  I tried running few Linux commands in Jupyter notebook and the result is shown below:

[image]

As you can see I am able to run `ls` Command but not able to run `cat` command. I tried Executing `cat` command like `!cat` but then it gets unrecognized as it's shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshots one can see, that IPython is part of the error messages. [Jupyter notebook is using IPython](https://ipython.org/notebook.html) in the background when you are in Windows and running these commands.

[IPython documentation about magic commands:](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#line-magics)

> For posix systems, the default aliases are ‘cat’, ‘cp’, ‘mv’, ‘rm’, ‘rmdir’, and ‘mkdir’, and other platform-specific aliases are added.
>
> For windows-based systems, the default aliases are ‘copy’, ‘ddir’, ‘echo’, ‘ls’, ‘ldir’, ‘mkdir’, ‘ren’, and ‘rmdir’.

That is why the Linux `ls` will work, but the `cat` command does not work for IPython on Windows.

Note: IPython is not a comandline tool. For a Linux comandline tool on Windows try [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin).

Comment: Cygwin Worked for me !